# How can I add a new DWORD using a batch script?

Tags: windows-7, batch, windows-registry, regedit

How can I add a new DWORD using a batch script? I know you need to have a elevated command prompt (I think) which I already have the script for. This is the script I have but it’s not working.

```
REG ADD HKLM\Software\Microsoft\windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\system] [/v LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy] [/t REG_DWORD] [/d 1][/f]
```

And yes I am using this for PStools.

Comment: Have you tried it without the square brackets?

Comment: yes i have, and also with quotation marks.

Comment: BTW, if you're working in HKCU, you probably don't need to elevate privileges.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### This is the script I have but it’s not working.

> ```
> REG ADD HKLM\Software\Microsoft\windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\system] [/v LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy] [/t REG_DWORD] [/d 1][/f]
> ```

The <kbd>[</kbd> and <kbd>]</kbd> are not meant to be part of the command (it looks like you copied some text from a page explaining the command and did not remove them). These characters are used as delimiters (grouping characters) when explaining how to use the `reg` command.

Try the following:

```
REG ADD HKLM\Software\Microsoft\windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\system /v LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
```

See [REG.exe](http://ss64.com/nt/reg.html) for more information about the syntax of `reg`. It also has some examples.

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [reg](http://ss64.com/nt/reg.html) - Read, Set or Delete registry keys and values, save and restore from a .REG file.